# Не получается эмулировать post запрос через curl

Tags: php, post, curl, token

Ребят, прошу помощи, столкнулся с такой проблемой, для работы раньше использовали post запрос и просто передавали куки ( в пост передавали фиксированный токен) сейчас сайт сделал динамический токен и все похерилось.
Пытаюсь решить через curl но понимаю что сам не справляюсь.

- Для эмуляция запроса
- со страницы https://tk-kit.ru/rates
- в поле откуда пишем Москва (выбрать из выпадающего списка)
- поле куда, нажимаем желтую кнопку (Выбрать все возможные пункты назначения)
- Элемент списка

Д

```
<?php $curl = curl_init(); //инициализация сеанса
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tk-kit.ru/rates/validate-end?send=1'); //урл сайта к которому обращаемся
$html = file_get_contents('https://tk-kit.ru/rates/');
preg_match('/<meta name="csrf-token" content="(.*?)"/isu',$html, $match );
$token = $match[1];
echo $token.'<br>';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //выводим заголовки
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //передача данных методом POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //теперь curl вернет нам ответ, а не выведет
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, //тут переменные которые будут переданы методом POST
array (
        '_csrf' => $token,
        'RatesForm[all]' => '1',
        'RatesForm[type]' => '2',
        'RatesForm[viwe_price]' => '1',
        'RatesForm[transport_out_code][]' => '0000007700',
        'RatesForm[city_out_name][]=' => 'Москва',
        'RatesForm[city_out]' => ''
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://tk-kit.ru/rates/");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
$headers[] = 'X-Csrf-Token: '.$token;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: tkkit=tlejtr2dn6gd4lbj33rrotdvmc; _csrf=2ca3f41cdb7ea1be9f173f9de7657b25008a7a21495312c8edcbdd4960497c5ca%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22-vt-DUty-pvnyjv2Qf-0GDuQBiu9a5GO%22%3B%7D; geography-tkkit=d070f42dfc41a33c9c88e92f82b328196de2ccfaa9a26c7cc220cc56c2c80877a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A15%3A%22geography-tkkit%22%3Bi%3A1%3Ba%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A22%3A%22detected_sxgeo_city_id%22%3Bi%3A466885%3Bs%3A17%3A%22geography_city_id%22%3Bi%3A710%3Bs%3A13%3A%22sxgeo_city_id%22%3Bi%3A1486209%3Bs%3A15%3A%22kladr_city_code%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22660000100000%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22confirm%22%3Bi%3A1%3B%7D%7D';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Te: Trailers';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$res = curl_exec($curl);
//если ошибка то печатаем номер и сообщение
if(!$res) {
    $error = curl_error($curl).'('.curl_errno($curl).')';
    echo $error;
}
else {
    echo $res;
}
curl_close($curl);
```

?>
Буду благодарен за конструктивные ответы.
Возможно тут совсем не такой подход нужен?
Насколько я понимаю, я 2 раза инициализирую запрос к сайту, поэтому и получаю 2 разных ответа токена, как с делать в одном не представляю.

Comment: А где обработка Cookie? google->curl+cookie

Comment: добавил, но особо не помогло.

Comment: Где?)) Где в вашем вопросе работа с куками? Суть того что вам нужно - не в ручную ставить куки, а проходить авторизацию и между запросами сохранять куки, для этого вам надо включить этот механизм в curl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885538/php-curl-and-cookies

Comment: Владимир, как я понял вы говорите вот про эти строки

Comment: $tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname );

Comment: Именно про них, но помимо них - авторизацию нужно выполнять из php

Comment: Честно, погуглил, нашел более менее понятное вот такое https://xdan.ru/avtorizacija-na-sajte-pri-pomoshhi-curl-php.html но так и не понял как это сделать. может еще более развернуто есть ?

Comment: Куда же еще подробней? изучаем форму логина, и дальше по очереди всё тоже самое что делает браузер повторяем =)

Comment: Но у меня же нет логина и пароля, чего-то я не понимаю видимо. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: а откуда берется кука из примера кода?))https://yadi.sk/i/aXshKzykZ169IA

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95974/discussion-between---and-kreol2013).